Azure Policy for SQL Database Long Term Retention
I am trying to deploy an Azure Policy to automatically set Azure Database LTR parameters.
However, the compliance auditing works, but the deployment doesn't. I tried looking at the documentation and other examples but can't seem to figure it out. Below is the complete policy definition.
I did manage to get this working for other backup types, so I am at a loss here.
{
  "mode": "Indexed",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases"
        },
        {
          "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
          "equals": "[parameters('tagValue')]"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "[parameters('effect')]",
      "details": {
        "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/backupLongTermRetentionPolicies",
        "name": "default",
        "roleDefinitionIds": [
          "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/9b7fa17d-e63e-47b0-bb0a-15c516ac86ec"
        ],
        "existenceCondition": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/backupLongTermRetentionPolicies/monthlyRetention",
              "equals": "[parameters('LTRMonthlyRetention')]"
            },
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/backupLongTermRetentionPolicies/weeklyRetention",
              "equals": "[parameters('LTRWeeklyRetention')]"
            },
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/backupLongTermRetentionPolicies/weekOfYear",
              "equals": "[parameters('LTRWeekOfYear')]"
            },
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/backupLongTermRetentionPolicies/yearlyRetention",
              "equals": "[parameters('LTRYearlyRetention')]"
            }
          ]
        },
        "deployment": {
          "properties": {
            "mode": "incremental",
            "template": {
              "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
              "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
              "parameters": {
                "serverName": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "LTRMonthlyRetention": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "LTRWeeklyRetention": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "LTRWeekOfYear": {
                  "type": "Integer"
                },
                "LTRYearlyRetention": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "resources": [
                {
                  "name": "[concat(parameters('serverName'),'/default')]",
                  "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/backupLongTermRetentionPolicies",
                  "apiVersion": "2017-10-01-preview",
                  "properties": {
                    "monthlyRetention": "[parameters('LTRMonthlyRetention')]",
                    "weeklyRetention": "[parameters('LTRWeeklyRetention')]",
                    "weekOfYear": "[parameters('LTRWeekOfYear')]",
                    "yearlyRetention": "[parameters('LTRYearlyRetention')]"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            "parameters": {
              "serverName": {
                "value": "[field('fullname')]"
              },
              "LTRMonthlyRetention": {
                "value": "[parameters('LTRMonthlyRetention')]"
              },
              "LTRWeeklyRetention": {
                "value": "[parameters('LTRWeeklyRetention')]"
              },
              "LTRWeekOfYear": {
                "value": "[parameters('LTRWeekOfYear')]"
              },
              "LTRYearlyRetention": {
                "value": "[parameters('LTRYearlyRetention')]"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "effect": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Effect",
        "description": "Enable or disable the execution of the policy."
      },
      "allowedValues": [
        "DeployIfNotExists",
        "Disabled"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "DeployIfNotExists"
    },
    "LTRMonthlyRetention": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "LTRMonthlyRetention",
        "description": null
      },
      "defaultValue": "3"
    },
    "LTRWeeklyRetention": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "LTRWeeklyRetention",
        "description": null
      },
      "defaultValue": "3"
    },
    "LTRWeekOfYear": {
      "type": "Integer",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "LTRWeekOfYear",
        "description": null
      },
      "defaultValue": 3
    },
    "LTRYearlyRetention": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "LTRYearlyRetention",
        "description": null
      },
      "defaultValue": "3"
    },
    "tagValue": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "BackupTag Value",
        "description": "Value of the tag, such as '3'"
      },
      "defaultValue": "3"
    },
    "tagName": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Tag Name",
        "description": "Value of the tag, such as 'backup'"
      },
      "defaultValue": "backup"
    }
  }
}


When you say the deployment doesn't work what's the error message? Look at the 'Activity Logs' on the corresponding Azure SQL Server and you should see an entry for the deployIfNotExists policy, with an error.

The error is literally "InvalidDeployment" with the following extra text: 
The deployment definition is invalid. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details.

Make sure that the parameter values provided in the policy definition match the expected data types and formats.
For example, LTRWeekOfYear is defined as an integer, so ensure that the value provided is a valid integer.

@alex, I did. The String parameters for the retention are set as "P2M" for example, or P2Y for the yearly retention.
The Integer parameter is just 4.
However, I would expect a better error if this was really the issue.
